# Autocompletetextview with multiple variables

Tags: android

I have a JSON :

```
{"results":[
    {"id":"21","name":"Jonny"},
    {"id":"22","name":"Samuel"},
    {"id":"23","name":"Martha"}
    ]}
```

I need to put "name" into an **autocompletetextview**.

I need to post "id" to other activity, based on selected name in autocompletetextview.

Please help, thanks in advance

Comment: what do you use to deserialize json ?

Comment: i've add "name" to a list on autocompletetextview adapter.
i successfully post "id" by adding 2 spinner, 1 spinner for name and 1 spinner for id, but i required to use autocompletetextview for name in this task.

Answer (score 0):

First convert json to hashmap:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> result = readJson("Your json string here");


public HashMap<String, Integer> readJson(String json) {
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);

        // Getting JSON Array node
        JSONArray results = jsonObj.getJSONArray("results");
        final int j = results.length();
        HashMap<String, Integer> resultMap = new HashMap<>(j);
        for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
            JSONObject item = results.getJSONObject(i);
            resultMap.put(item.getString("name"), item.getInt("id"));
        }
        return resultMap;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now set autocomplete adapter like:

```
autoComplete.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, new ArrayList<>(result.keySet())));

public void startNextActivity(int id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), NextActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("id", id);
    getContext().startActivity(intent);
}
```

call the start activity like:

```
        startNextActivity(result.get(autoComplete.getText().toString()));
```

Comment: thanks @subhash, i'll try it.
have any suggest how to get 'id' of selected 'name' in current activity without passing it to next activity..?

Comment: result.get(autoComplete.getText().toString())